# File creation failing when using oozie

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

I want to create some output files using shell script as a part of my project. The process works fine when the script is run independently.

But fails with below error when I try to integrate with Oozie workflow:

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

Sample workflow:

```
<action name="scr-filecreation">
     <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
         <configuration>
             <property>
                 <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                 <value>${queueName}</value>
             </property>
         </configuration>
         <exec>${SimpleFileCreation}</exec>
         <argument>${filedir}</argument>
         <file>${SimpleFileCreation}#${SimpleFileCreation}</file>
         <capture-output/>
     </shell>
<ok to="income-success" />
<error to="income-failure" />
</action>
```

Below is the simple script to create a file with a few lines: fileCreate.sh

```
echo $1 > $1/file.txt
count_val1=`cat dir1/* | wc -l`
count_val2=`cat dir2/* | wc -l`
echo $count_acct >> $1/file.txt
echo $count_cust >> $1/file.txt
```

Comment: You need to check the logs for the MR job. The issue could be related to anything. And what is the value for `SimpleFileCreation` parameter?

Comment: Please update the question with the MR error log..